# Is "deliverer" an common/acceptable alternative of "delivery boy" or "delivery guy"?

Tags: word-usage

Someone told me that "deliverer" sounded strange. However, deliverer seems to be synonyms with "delivery boy" and "delivery guy":

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deliverer

> to carry and turn over (letters, goods, etc.) to the intended
>   recipient or recipients: to deliver mail; to deliver a package.

Would it be weird, though, for example? Call a McDonald's delivery guy a "deliverer"?

Comment: It does sound strange. I recommend using "carrier" or "messenger" instead depending on the context.

Comment: It's also not uncommon to hear *delivery person*.

Comment: I've downvoted because you ask about the noun **deliverer** but give us a definition for the verb **deliver**  If you really have a question about the noun, go to a dictionary, or to a couple of dictionaries, which actually have an entry for that noun. A **deliverer** is a savior, someone who rescues you from danger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Deliverer" seems like it should be an acceptable alternative to "delivery boy/girl/person", but it isn't. However, this is not because of its phonology, as Omnidisciplinarianist speculates, because **"deliverer" *is* an English word** that people use quite regularly in certain circles -- however, **it's used to mean something entirely different, so it cannot be used for "delivery person"**.

While the verb "to deliver" is most often used for bringing someone something and giving it to them, it has several other definitions. One of these definitions is "to rescue, to save, to set free". Consider the phrase "deliver us from evil", from the Lord's Prayer -- it means "save/rescue us from evil". **"Deliverer" is based on this meaning of "to deliver" and is a synonym of "savior, rescuer, messiah"**. You're unlikely to encounter it outside of religious contexts, in my experience, but it's used quite frequently in many translations of the Bible, as well as in sermons, the lyrics of hymns and contemporary Christian music, and in other Christian contexts.

So, is the McDonald's delivery guy your deliverer? Depends how badly you needed that McDonald's.

Comment: "Depends how badly you needed that McDonald's." Lol, excellent ...

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, both Jason Bassford's and holydragon's comments are spot on.

Deliverer sounds weird. Carrier, messenger, and delivery person do not.

Likely because the suffix *-er* doesn't sit well on a word that already ends in those very same letters.